# Post back the data if validation fails for "Select"

Tags: php

Once submitted selected option, the data is not stored. 
just want to know how to post back the data if validation fails

The following line doesnt really work for me.

```
    <select id="numbers" name="numbers" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['numbers'])) ? $_POST['numbers'] : " "; ?>"/>
```

if someone could give me a hand?

Many thanks, here is my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['numbers']) &&($_POST['fruits']) && $_POST['numbers'] != "null" && $_POST['fruits'] !== "null")
{
  echo "Thank you!";
} elseif  (isset($_POST['numbers']) && $_POST['numbers'] = "null") {
    echo "you forgot to choose a number";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['fruits']) && $_POST['fruits'] = "null")
{
    echo "you forgot to choose fruit name";
    }

?>



  <form id="form" name="form"  method="post" action="">

      <label for="expiry">Select</label>
                <select id="numbers" name="numbers" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['numbers'])) ? $_POST['numbers'] : " "; ?>"/>
                <option value="null" selected="selected">-</option>
                <option  value="01">01</option>
                <option value="02">02</option>
                <option value="03">03</option>
              </select>

                <select id="fruits" name="fruits" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['fruits']))? $_POST['fruits'] : ''; ?>"/>
                <option value="null" selected="selected">-</option>
                <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
                <option value="Pear">Pear</option>

              </select>

   <input type="submit" value="Send"  />
  </form>
```

Solved it, Maybe not a best way, but at least got it sorted:

```
<?php
$item = null; # 
$itemyear = null; 

if(isset($_POST['numbers'])){
$item = $_POST['numbers'];
}
if(isset($_POST['fruits'])){
$itemyear = $_POST['fruits'];
}



if(isset($item) && isset($itemyear) && $item != "null" && $itemyear !== "null")
{
  echo "Thank you!";
} elseif  ($item == "null") {
    echo "you forgot to choose a number";
    }
    elseif($itemyear == "null")
{
echo "you forgot to choose fruit name";
}



?>



  <form id="form" name="form"  method="post" action="">

      <label for="expiry">Select</label>
            <select id="numbers" name="numbers" />
                <option value="null" selected="selected">-</option>
                <option  value="01" <?php if($item == '01'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?>>01</option>
                <option value="02" <?php if($item == '02'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?>>02</option>
                <option value="03" <?php if($item == '03'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?>>03</option>
              </select>

              <select id="fruits" name="fruits" />
                <option value="null" selected="selected">-</option>
                <option value="Apple"<?php if($itemyear == 'Apple'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >Apple</option>
                <option value="Banana"<?php if($itemyear == 'Banana'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?>>Banana</option>
                <option value="Pear"<?php if($itemyear == 'Pear'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?>>Pear</option>

              </select>

   <input type="submit" value="Send"  />
  </form>


<?php 
echo $item ."-". $itemyear;
?>
```

Comment: I really don't udnerstand what you mean. Also it should be <?php echo isset($_POST['numbers']); ?>. I don't see why you would want to print a boolean value into the value attribute though.

Comment: Thank you. Once submitted selected option, the data is not stored. just want to know how to post back the data if validation fails

Answer (score 0):

the PHP isset() function returns either true or false (depending on whether the input is.. well... set.

You would want to use this:
`value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['numbers'])) ? $_POST['numbers'] : ""; ?>`

Comment: Thank you but doesnt work,  <select id="numbers" name="numbers" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['numbers'])? $_POST['numbers'] : ''; ?>"/>, if I made wrong? thanks again

Comment: You are missing the conditional paranthesis around the isset. a ternary operator goes as such: [action] (condition) ? [if true] : [if false]; . In your case you used "isset($_POST)" when you need "(isset($_POST))"

Comment: Thank you TurdPile for taking time had a look the code, but it still doesnt work is this right expression:  <select id="numbers" name="numbers" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['numbers'])) ? $_POST['numbers'] : " "; ?>"/>

Comment: What is being returned? If nothing is being return it is probably throwing out the "false" part of the conditional, meaning $_POST['numbers'] was not set

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a `value` attribute on a `<select>`. You have to find the correct `<option>` and set its `selected` attribute. Personally, I put a `data-default` attribute on the `<select>` and then use JavaScript to loop through the options and find the right one.

Comment: Thanks Kolink, I had Javascript validation, just want to learn how to use php to validate forms. your answer is helpful.

Comment: I don't appreciate you saying "your answer is helpful" when you clearly didn't understand a word of what I just said. I didn't say anything about JavaScript validation, I said you can put an attribute on the select and use JavaScript to find the correct option to make it work.

Comment: No, I know what you meant! The answer helps as you said: "You can't set a value attribute on a <select>. You have to find the correct <option> and set its selected attribute." Also I found a bit help from this tut. http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/pb-drop.php

Comment: And what about the whole part where you use a loop to go through `select[data-default] > option` and find the one with the right value?

Answer (score 0):

Oh now I see.

I don't know what the usual thing to do is but one way is to put all the data as a query string when you redirect the user back. The reason why it doesn't stay in the $_POST global is because it's only kept on the page you post to then it's gone.

So when you redirect the user back

```
if(validationFailed)
{
    header("Location: page.php?data=example");
}
```

The data can then be retrieved in page.php by using

```
$data = $_GET['data']; // contains "example"
```